# Elaticsearch stuck using 99% cpu and all shards are Initializing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inherited an ElasticSearch and Kibana setup from a former collegue and now it has stopped responding. 
We use this to collect logs from our system so it is constantly coming in new data that needs to be processed.

I first notices that Kibana couldn't connect to elasticsearch so I logged into the VM running the cluster and found that none of the nodes were connected.
I also found the VM to be very sluggish. Turns out elasticsearch is using up all the cpu.

I then run:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards
```

Which shows me that all of my primary shards are stuck in the state "INITIALIZING". 
Any suggestions as how to solve this problem?
I have tried to run a few commands, like reroute and also just delete the whole index, but i always get a timeout exception.

EDIT:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v

    host     ip       heap.percent ram.percent  load node.role master name          
x.x.x.x x.x.x.x           47          59 -1.00 d         *      Cecelia Reyes


http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v

    index    shard prirep state        docs store ip       node          
offboard 1     p      INITIALIZING            x.x.x.x Cecelia Reyes 
offboard 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                     
offboard 4     p      INITIALIZING            x.x.x.x Cecelia Reyes 
offboard 4     r      UNASSIGNED                                     
offboard 2     p      UNASSIGNED                                     
offboard 2     r      UNASSIGNED                                     
offboard 3     p      INITIALIZING            x.x.x.x Cecelia Reyes 
offboard 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                     
offboard 0     p      INITIALIZING            x.x.x.x Cecelia Reyes 
offboard 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                     
.kibana  0     p      UNASSIGNED                                     
.kibana  0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Just a small cutout:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/pending_tasks?v

insertOrder timeInQueue priority source                             
      4        1.2h HIGH     cluster_reroute(async_shard_fetch) 
      5        1.2h HIGH     _add_listener_
```

50 ish more of _add_listener_

Comment: 99% CPU is not a good sign... What about your heap usage? Can you update your question with `http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v` + `http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v` + `http://localhost:9200/_cat/pending_tasks?v`?

Comment: Added. I sorry for the shitty formating. Didn't manage to make it any better. @Val

Comment: You should print that out in cat textual format, it's more legible than JSON

Comment: Well I am using Postman in Windows, so no cat :) @Val

Comment: That's because Postman sends `application/json` in a content-type header. Add `&format=text`to all your queries or change that header to `text/plain` instead

Comment: Ahh, sweet! But I did some manual editing before this and i hope that is readable enough. @Val

Comment: Please use the text format.

Comment: Now they are added as text @Val