# Removing Elasticsearch index offline

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a problem with an elasticsearch instance that refuses to start up and is stuck on Initializing. [Elaticsearch stuck using 99% cpu and all shards are Initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41439814/3280515)

My guess is that something is wrong with the data stored in one of the indexes. So I am thinking I might just go ahead and remove all the logs and start over. This is not a production system and the logs so far will probably never be used.

However, since the system is still stuck with trying to recover I am not able to remove the index using the REST API. 
So i was thinking I could probably remove it manually by removing the physical file/folder. 
 So my questions are:

1. Which file/folder should I remove?
2. Is it possible to just move the file/folder and recover them again later if I figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not posting your ES version , I will assume that you are running version `2.x`

In my local version `elasticsearch-2.3.5` and based on my cluster configuration :

```
 cluster.name: local
```

Data is stored at

> elasticsearch-2.3.5\data\CLUSTERNAME\nodes\x\indices

Where x is the number of the node.

The folder structure here is as follows :

[image]

So if you have `only one node` where replication is not present , if you backup that folder and restore it later , it is okay to do so. Now , if we're talking about more than one node . You will need to stop both nodes before you try to do such operation to avoid possible conflicts.

Steps I did :

```
-Stop ElasticSearch

-Backup `elasticsearch-2.3.5\data\local`

-Remove `elasticsearch-2.3.5\data\local`

-Start the server
```

Comment: I am using ES 2.4.0. Is "local" the name of your elasticsearch cluster? By default it seems to be named "elasticsearch".

Comment: @jimmy That seems to be the case. I edited the answer.

Comment: My folder structure under data looks like this: data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\indices and data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\_state 
Is that the case also for you? @Yeikel

Comment: @jimmy My folder structure is similar. Let me add that the answer as well

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, but it might be worth adding that ALL indices on that node disappears.

Comment: @jimmy That's what you're trying to accomplish right? If you want to delete an specif indice go to nodes\0\indices and nodes\1\indices and delete the specific you're looking for

Comment: Actually no, but i realize I was not very clear. Anyways I saw that before removing anything so thats fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @jimmy I see. I added that details to the answer because you're right when you say that it is not clear. Thank you for the clarifications.